# In PHP, how can I iterate through an array and change the key dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$people`. When I do `print_r($people)`, I get the following results:

```
[people] => Array
(
  [500] => Array
          (
              [firstName] => Fred
              [age] => 19
          )

  [501] => Array
          (
               [firstName] => Bob
               [age] => 12
          )
  [502] => Array
          (
               [firstName] => Steve
               [age] => 52
          )
)
```

I want to change all the keys to look more "normal", starting at 0, then 1, 2 etc. How can I achieve this? To clarify, I want the resulting array to look like this:

```
    [people] => Array
(
  [0] => Array
          (
              [firstName] => Fred
              [age] => 19
          )

  [1] => Array
          (
               [firstName] => Bob
               [age] => 12
          )
  [2] => Array
          (
               [firstName] => Steve
               [age] => 52
          )
)
```

Comment: Don't iterate, just use `array_values()` which will reset the keys for you: `$people['people'] = array_values($people['people']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will take only the values from an array, ignoring the keys and instead returning the array renumbered from zero.

```
$people = array_values($people);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```
foreach ($people as $value) {
  $people_new[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$people['people'] = array_values($people['people']);
print_r($people);
```